# How to Setup Proxy Target in React Native with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, axios, backend

Trying to configure proxy in react native with node to run axios calls.

Tried the following code in server/package.json

```
"proxy": {
    "/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "cd ../client && yarn ios",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  }
```

server/authRouter.js

```
const authRouter = require('express').Router();
authRouter.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('proxy success');
  });

module.exports = authRouter;
```

server/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const authRouter = require('./authRouter');
const app = express();
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

client/app.js

```
await axios.get('/auth/test');
```

When I run `yarn dev` and test an axios call, it logs the following error

```
 LOG      [Error: Network Error]
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the proxy directly in axios
http://localhost:5000/auth/test

I'm not sure why it doesn't work that way, even i had a problem in the past.